No transform from [link] to [other link] in Rviz
Despite going through several similar questions, I could not solve my problem.
I built a mobile robot but when launching RViz I get the following:

The weird thing is that, as you can see, only one TF is problematic and I don't know why.
    <joint name="rialzo_joint" type="prismatic">
        <parent link="amr_body"/>
        <child link="amr_rialzo"/>
        <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0"/>
        <limit lower="0" upper="0.06" velocity="0.02" effort="10"/>
        <axis xyz="0 0 1"/>
        <dynamics damping="0.1" friction="0.1" />
    </joint>

The joint between the two links seems to be alright.
The tree looks like this:

How do I solve?

Welcome to Robotics, dodo. In your tf tree graphic, I don't see the amr_rialzo frame. Does it exist, disconnected, in some other part of the graphic window? The code for the joint looks fine at a glance, so I'm wondering if maybe you forgot to define the link amr_rialzo? Can you please post the complete robot description?

Please edit your question to remove the answer from the question text. You can post the answer as an answer (you're allowed to answer your own questions!) and then you're able to mark it as the accepted answer. This will help future visitors quickly find the answer when they're facing the same problem you described.

I solved by inserting the gazebo plugin "libgazebo_ros_joint_state_publisher.so" and specifying the joint of interest,in this case "amr_rialzo", in the URDF.
